# Is it possible to create types in Julia at runtime?

Tags: julia

Let's say I want to have a function of the form

```
abstract RecordType
function CreateRecordType(fields_names::Vector{ASCIIString}, type_name::ASCIIString)
    # magic that creates the type type_name with string fields field_names
end
```

For example, `CreateRecordType(["name","age"], "Person")` would create a new type with the following definition:

```
type Person <: RecordType
    name::ASCIIString
    age::ASCIIString
end
```

Is this possible to do in Julia?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Approach 1: Parse to get an AST and then eval

Probably the easiest way is to create a string of what you want and then parse it to get an AST, and then eval the AST.  You can do any or all within the function.  Here's possible simple implementation that does it all

```
function CreateRecordType(typeName::ASCIIString,fieldNames::Array{ASCIIString,1},fieldTypes::Array{ASCIIString,1})
   s::ASCIIString = "type $typeName <: RecordType\n";

   for i = 1:length(fieldNames)
      s = s*"$(fieldNames[i])::$(fieldTypes[i])\n"
   end
   eval(parse(s*"end"));
   return;
end
```

#### Using it...

```
julia> abstract RecordType;

julia> CreateRecordType("Person",["name","age"],["ASCIIString","Int64"])

julia> bubba = Person("Bubba",2)
Person("Bubba",2)

julia> print(bubba.age)
2
```

That's probably not as efficient as it could be, instead you can take a look at the AST that parse produces and then create the *Expr* to make the AST directly and not use parse and not use a string.

### Approach 2: Making the AST directly

Here's an alternate form that creates an AST, it's a little more safe because it requires types and symbols rather than opaque strings.  This was created by experimenting with the output of various parses as alluded to above.  Using *Dict* instead of 2 arrays is probably better because the field and the type must always be paired.

```
function createTypeAST(typeName::Symbol,parentType::Type,fields::Dict{Symbol,DataType})
   e = Expr(:type,true)
   push!(e.args,Expr(:<:));
   push!(e.args[2].args,typeName);
   push!(e.args[2].args,parentType);
   push!(e.args,Expr(:block))
   for field in fields
      push!(e.args[3].args,:($(field[1])::$(field[2])));
   end
   return e;
end
```

#### 2nd form in action

```
julia> x = createTypeAST(:P1,RecordType,Dict(:a => Int64))
:(type P1<:RecordType
        a::Int64
    end)

julia> eval(x)

julia> y = P1(1)
P1(1)

julia> y.a
1
```