# Is it possible to implement a type factory in Julia without using `eval()`?

Tags: class, julia, factory

For example, I have an abstract type for the base type, and I want to implement a type factory that dynamically creates concrete types under this abstract type, with names (and other type traits) given by user input arguments.

```
abstract type AbstractFoo end

function TypeFactory(typename::String, supertype::DataType)
    ...
    return ConcreteSubtype
end
```

The function `TypeFactory` takes `typename` and `supertype` arguments and creates a concrete type that belongs to the `supertype` and has the same name as `typename`.

I know this kind of class factory is not too difficult to implement in Python (e.g., [How can I dynamically create derived classes from a base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15247075/how-can-i-dynamically-create-derived-classes-from-a-base-class)). In Julia, it can be imitated by using `eval(parse())` to evaluate string expressions ([Is it possible to create types in Julia at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27083816/is-it-possible-to-create-types-in-julia-at-runtime)). But it looks to me that this solution is not a true type factory in an object-oriented sense. Is it possible to have a type factory in Julia that behaves like those in OOP languages (Python, C#, etc.)?

---

Edit [8 Feb 2018]:

My bad for not expressing things clearly. I'm new to Julia and had just recently started coding my project in it. I knew that inheritance is not supported and did not meant to get around with that in Julia.

Coming from a Python background, I had some feeling that `eval()` is usually meant for prototyping but not for production code. Of course Julia is different and is far more efficient than pure Python, but the code given to `eval()` still has to be compiled at the runtime (correct me if I'm wrong). And its use is sorted of discouraged too, from the perspective of performance ([Julia, speeding up eval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20174352/julia-speeding-up-eval)).

And by 'user input' I didn't mean solely command-line input. They could be supplied by a user's config file. (That being said, @SalchiPapa's macro solution is both apt and elegant!)

Comment: What do you mean by "not a true type factory in an object-oriented sense"? IIUC, you're looking for something like `type()` in Python, to me, that's exactly the `createTypeAST`+`eval` in the approach 2 in the linked answer. It's a helper function that allows users to dynamically create a new type at runtime, I'm wondering how does this connect to OOP.

Comment: @Gnimuc I think he is referring to inheritance.

Comment: @Gnimuc Thanks for asking. I was not being clear. I think I wanted it to be function-like, which returns the concrete type, not an expression evaluated with `eval()`. One reason is that precompiled code is faster than code that is `eval`-ed at the runtime. Also, I think writing functions (and macros) in production code is more elegant, though it may just be a personal preference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to implement a type factory in Julia without using `eval()`?

You could use a macro:

- https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/metaprogramming/#man-macros-1

> Macros provide a method to include generated code in the final body of a program. A macro maps a tuple of arguments to a returned *expression*, and **the resulting expression is compiled directly rather than requiring a runtime `eval()` call**.

```rb
julia> VERSION
v"0.7.0-DEV.2098"

julia> module Factory
       export @factory
       macro factory(type_name::Symbol, super_type::Symbol)
           # ...
           return quote
               struct $type_name <: $(esc(super_type))
                   # ...
                   bar
               end
               return $(esc(type_name))
           end
       end
       end
Main.Factory

julia> using Main.Factory: @factory

julia> abstract type AbstractFoo end

julia> @factory ConcreteFoo AbstractFoo
ConcreteFoo

julia> foo = ConcreteFoo(42)
ConcreteFoo(42)

julia> foo.bar
42

julia> ConcreteFoo <: AbstractFoo
true

julia> supertype(ConcreteFoo)
AbstractFoo
```

Edit according to @Gnimuc understanding in the comments, using `input`:

```rb
julia> module Factory
       export @factory

       function input(prompt::String="")::String
           print(prompt)
           return chomp(readline())
       end

       macro factory(type_name = input("Type name: "))
           AbstractT = Symbol(:Abstract, type_name)
           ConcreteT = Symbol(:Concrete, type_name)
           return quote
               abstract type $(esc(AbstractT)) end
               struct $ConcreteT <: $(esc(AbstractT))
                   bar
               end
               return $(esc(AbstractT)), $(esc(ConcreteT))
           end
       end
       end
Main.Factory

julia> using Main.Factory: @factory

julia> @factory
Type name: Foo
(AbstractFoo, ConcreteFoo)

julia> @factory
Type name: Bar
(AbstractBar, ConcreteBar)

julia> @factory Baz
(AbstractBaz, ConcreteBaz)

julia> foo = ConcreteFoo(42)
ConcreteFoo(42)

julia> foo.bar
42

julia> ConcreteFoo <: AbstractFoo
true

julia> supertype(ConcreteFoo)
AbstractFoo

julia> @macroexpand @factory
Type name: Qux
quote
    #= REPL[1]:13 =#
    abstract type AbstractQux end
    #= REPL[1]:14 =#
    struct ConcreteQux <: AbstractQux
        #= REPL[1]:15 =#
        bar
    end
    #= REPL[1]:17 =#
    return (AbstractQux, ConcreteQux)
end

julia> eval(ans)
(AbstractQux, ConcreteQux)
```

Comment: As the OP said "with names given by user input arguments", maybe we need to add `type_name = readline(STDIN) |> Symbol` in the macro. But I think that's kinda runtime info, is it the best practice to insert the readline function into the macro implementation?

Comment: I'm curious how Python implements its `type()` function.

Comment: @Gnimuc I've updated my answer, taking into account your comments.